# Store new user information to Firebase with multiple view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have three different view controllers: (in this order) first+last name, birthday, email+password.
I have already connected my app to firebase and I know how to send the user information to firebase, but only for one of the view controllers. I want firebase to store all of the information from all three view controllers (name, birthday, and email/password) after clicking the "sign up" button on the last view controller (email+password). Please let me know how I can combine all of the information to one new user, rather than making them all new users.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are making multiple API calls rather than one single API to sign up a new user, meaning only one call is necessary. There are a couple of different ways you could do this, but the main idea is that you need to get all the data to the very end of the onboarding sign up and then call the Firebase API.

I suggest you make a data object called NewUser and store the data as you progress through the sign-up process. It would look something like this:

```
class NewUser {

    // MARK: - Variables

    var userID:String
    var name:String?
    var birthday:String?
    var email:String?
    var password:String?

    // MARK: - Init Variables

    init(userID:String, name:String, birthday:String, email:String, password:String) {

        self.userID = userID
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    }
}
```

Example to set name data:

`NewUser.name = name`

Then call `NewUser.name` to access the stored data.